# Accessibility of data member in member function before declaration of data member

Tags: c++, private-members, class-members

Consider this code:

```
class Test
{
public:

Test() { i = 0;  }

private:

int i;
};
```

Data member 'i' is used even before it is declared/defined. Should this not be a compilation error ? (It compiled fine!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that member functions  defined in the class definition are compiled as if they were defined immediately after the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't, within the context of the class definition, all members, data members or functions have complete visibility.

Answer (score 0):

where is the data member used before declaration?

```
class Test
{
public:

Test() { i = 0;  } // constructor

private:

int i;  //datamemeber
};
main()
{
Test obj; // memory allocated only here
}
```

the constructor is called after only the obj is created in main. then the memory for i is allocated. and the the constructor is called so there is scope and visibility for i

Answer (score 0):

This is because the body of a member function is a **complete-class context** of a class, as mentioned in the quoted statements below:

From [class.mem.general#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#6):

> **6.** A complete-class context of a class is a:
>
> - **function body** ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - default argument,
> - noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or
> - default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class.

Thus the constructor's body is a complete-class context of the class `Test` and so the usage of `i` inside the constructor is allowed here even though the data member `i` appear later, when writing the class definition.